# Can't change the height on the img

Tags: html, css

I need to lower the height of my image but px or % is not working. The logo is a img the should be a few px under the menu but because i'm not able to lower it's showing like its glue together.

```css
.Logo {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Logo-->
<div class="Logo">
  <img src="https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/md/20180411/md_5ace0628840fa.jpg">
</div>
<!-- Sobre nós -->


<!-- Produto -->


<!-- Nossa equipe -->

<!-- Contato -->
```

Comment: you can target img `.Logo img`

Comment: 5 px tall image?

Comment: Setting image height in css is the wrong solution

Answer (score 6):

You have to size the image, not the div surrounding it.

```
.Logo img{
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the class `.Logo` to `img` tag but not `div`.

```
<div>
    <img class="Logo" src="./img/logoG.png">
</div>
```

OR, in your CSS, you can do this:

```
.Logo img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Welcome!. I formatted your content and I am sure you meant `.Logo img` in your second suggestion but not just `.Logo`. Let me know if that was not your intention. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

CSS is about specificity. In your code, you're targeting the parent element of the logo - but when you want to set the height or width of an object, you need to target it directly.

```
.Logo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class (for example `imageClass`) to the img then in the css:

```
.imageClass {
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
}
```